# Why gradle build generates different jar file even though there is no change in source code?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle java project. When I ran `gradle build` several times, I found that each time the build task would generate a different jar file even though there was no change in the source code:
[image]

From the screenshot you can see the two times of running generated two different jar files with different MD5 digest, although the preceding tasks are UP-TO-DATE. 
So why gradle consider the build task as not UP-TO-DATE, and generate different jar files?
Or more specifically, why the `jar` task is considered as not UP-TO-DATE, and generate different jar files?

Comment: Timestamp differences

Comment: @Ian2thedv why the timestamp is significant? In my understanding, if the source code is not changed, the jar file is not necessary to generate again?

Comment: Did you specify the `clean` flag? This will regenerate the class files. You can check this by opening up the jar and comparing the md5sums of the individual classes

Comment: add --info parameter when you run build task, it will tell you why jar task is not UP-TO-DATE, then we will fix it

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Got following information after adding --info parameter: `:core/sample:jar (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:core/sample:jar
Executing task ':core/sample:jar' (up-to-date check took 0.379 secs) due to:
  Output file /Users/minggaoxi/Documents/Projects/JJCargo/code/athena-backend/core/sample/build/libs/sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar has changed.
:core/sample:jar (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.447 secs.`

Comment: @AdamSkywalker And if only run `gradle :core/sample:jar` for two times, then the second time it shows :core/sample:jar task is UP-TO-DATE.

Comment: according to logs, the problem is this file .../code/athena-backend/core/sample/buil‌​d/libs/sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  affects the jar task.  maybe build task modifies it somehow